# waiting for connection using do-while statement - java android

Tags: java, android, connection

Would like have your comments on this code.

```
private String getIpAddress(){
  String ip = "";
  try {
  Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
   while(enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()){
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
      while(enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()){
        InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

        String ipAddress = "";
        if(inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()){
           ipAddress = "SiteLocalAddress: ";

           ip += inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n"; 
        }
       }

   } catch (SocketException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
   }

 return ip;
 }

private void MDConnector() {
  setMobileDataEnabled (MainActivity.this,true);
  String ip = getIpAddress();
    do {
         addMessage("..")
         try{
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
         }catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException){
         }
      }while (ip.length() <= 0);
     MDConnect();
 }
```

its doesn't work. my goal is: connect->getIPAddress->if none, wait until i got one->then move to another method.
What wrong with my code? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added the getIpAddress code. credits to http://android-er.blogspot.jp/2014/02/get-my-ip-address.html

Comment: You chose the title of your question as “waiting for connection using do-while statement - java android” and tagged it “do-while”. I suggest you reconsider what tags are and how to use them (they are 1- for people who can answer your question to find it 2- for people who have the same question in the future to be able to find yours).

Comment: sorry for that. i dont know what tag to use. thanks for that  :)

Comment: I have added the “java” and “android” tags. Few of the site's old-timers follow tags such as “connection” or “do-while” (who is interested in “do-while”?). There is also a “dalvik” tag with many followers, feel free to use it if you think it applies to your question. You are allowed up to 5 tags. Well-chosen tags mean your question is seen by the right persons, so choose them carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In your do-while loop the ip-String does not get changed. Try moving the part where you get the IP for your ip-String into the try-block.

Comment: i've got another method for the getIpAddress which i got from here. it should change when my mobile data connects. until then the method should wait it to change.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would update your question with the Method you mentioned including more details like when and where it is called.

Comment: It still looks for me like the Function getIpAdress() is doing its work and **after** it tries to get the correct IP-Adress you loop with your do-while loop. In think my answer is still valid, just try to move the part String ip = getIpAddress() **into** the do-part of your loop (so just move your String ip = getIpAddress(); call one line further down).